# openerp ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

i am trying to get the current user name that make validate to invoice and i am writing this code

```
class account_invoice(orm.Model):

    _name="account.invoice"
    _inherit="account.invoice"


    def _get_validated_user(self, cr, uid, field_name, arg, context):
        result={}
        current_user=self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
        for user_id in current_user:
            if uid in current_user.id:
                result[current_user.id]=current_user.login
        # inv_obj=self.browse(cr,uid,ids)
        # user_name=inv_obj.write(cr, uid, {'validated_by': current_user})


    _columns = {
        'validated_by': fields.char('Validated_By',size=30),

        'user_name': fields.function(
            _get_validated_user,
            type='char',
            method=True,
            string='User Name'),
    }
```

when i try to install my custom module i get this error

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

where is the error ??

Comment: That error has no context. You need the lines preceding this error message to actually debug something.

Comment: should you not be using your field_name or arg parameter somewhere?

Comment: i have modified my function to
    <pre>
def _get_validated_user(self, cr, uid,context=None):
        result={}
        current_user=self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid)
        for user_id in current_user:
            if uid in current_user.id:
                result[current_user.id]=current_user.login
</pre>

Comment: steel get the same error

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature is wrong both times.  Functional field method signatures are:

```
def _my_func(self, cr, uid, ids, field, arg, context = None):
```

Your original method is missing ids argument and your second is missing ids, field and arg.  Note the field and arg arguments are almost never used.

The actual error message is slightly misleading but is python trying to match the number of items in the tuple passed as arguments to the method signature.